# Re-triggering of alerts in GCP Stack driver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I want to configure stack driver alerts in such a way that until threshold value doesn't meet it keeps on sending alert emails.
In present scenario I am getting alert email once when value changes and recovery alert when threshold value achieved what I want is that continues mails of alerts like after every 10 min so that if team miss one mail then we can still get more notifications so that chances of any miss reduced.
Same as other monitoring tools does like Nagios etc. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/153940230) for your issue and you will get further update on that issue tracker. If you have any other questions or queries please feel free to ask there.